# How can I set max value(range) for y-axis and bar width of a bar chart using nvd3.js

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I have generated a bar chart for the data to show ratings of five topics on scale of 5 (Ratings).On x-axis I showed Topic names.

```
        $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'discreteBarChart',
            height: 450,
            margin: {
                top: 20,
                right: 20,
                bottom: 50,
                left: 55
            },
            x: function(d) {
                return d.label;
            },
            y: function(d) {
                return d.value;
            },
            showValues: true,
            duration: 500,
            xAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'X Axis'
            },
            yAxis: {
                axisLabel: 'Y Axis',
                axisLabelDistance: -10
              }
            }
         };
        $scope.data = [{
            values: $scope.Details.ratings              
        }];
```

HTML:

```
 <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
```

On y-axis the max value should be 5, but here it is taking the maximum value among the data and the bars in the bar chart are having large width. How can I change the bar width and max range on y-axis?

Comment: This is way too broad.  Instead of listing requirements for a program and hoping someone will provide code to fulfill it, you should present the code you tried and what failed when you implemented it.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you @Claies but am new to charts and I tried using Angular Charts, Fusion Charts, C3.js and all but am unable to find exact match for my requirement. So I am expecting some suggestions like about proper source to full fill my requirement.

Comment: that doesn't make your question a better fit for the site, if anything, that makes the question a worse fit.  from http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - "4.Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thanks @Claies for correcting me. I am new to stackoverflow. I have uploaded the code snippet which I tried using [nvd3.js](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart)

Answer (score 0):

i used the following code to set bar width and adjust the bar curvature

```
enter code here
dispatch: {
    renderEnd: function (e) {
d3.selectAll("rect.nv-bar").attr('rx', 4).attr('ry', 4).attr('width', 15)
}
    }
```

putting

```
groupSpacing : 0.57,
```

in chart dict will also help to adjust width dynamically